# Convert Keras model to CoreML on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, keras, coreml

Is it possible to convert Keras model to Apple's CoreML on Ubuntu?

Is OSX required to run the scripts in the page [Converting Trained Models to Core ML](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml/converting_trained_models_to_core_ml)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can absolutely install coremltools 0.4.0 on Linux Ubuntu 16.04 (I am using "Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS"). I have just ran my convert.py script which proves it is possible with Keras using TF backend.

Make sure that you have:

1. using python 2.7
2. have updated pip to 9.0.1
3. have activated your virualenv (if you are using)

Comment: Thank you. I've only tried python 3, missed python version prerequisites.

Answer (score 3):

**TL:DR** It is possible to convert Keras model to CoreML format on Ubuntu, but it cannot be verified.

Since coremltools is a Python package it can be used for conversion on almost on any platform that supports Python. Conversion of the model to CoreML format happens successfully but it cannot be tested. In the sense we cannot test the conversion using predict method. That is [coremltools.models.MLModel.predict](https://apple.github.io/coremltools/generated/coremltools.models.MLModel.html#coremltools.models.MLModel.predict) method cannot be used. This method requires macOS High Sierra since it makes of the CoreML framework on macOS, otherwise an exception like the one below will be raised.

```
Exception: Model prediction is only supported on macOS version 10.13.
```

Answer (score 1):

Keras 2 and Sklearn converters in coremltools 0.4.0 definitely work fine on Ubuntu. 
I've just trained several models and converted them on Ubuntu. After importing to Xcode everything works.

Comment: I can't even install it.
"No matching distribution found for coremltools" on Ubuntu 16.04